# MariaDB: REGEX with [.character.] doesnt work anymore ('POSIX collating elements are not supported)

Tags: regex, mariadb, posix

I have an error that is driving me crazy. When I take the following MySQL REGEX example from the official MySQL page i get an error. Used SQL-Statement:

```
SELECT '~' REGEXP '[[.tilde.]]';
```

Error message I get:

```
#1139 - Got error 'POSIX collating elements are not supported at offset 1' from regexp
```

Source of the example (scroll down to [.characters.]): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: Are you using MariaDB instead of MySQL?

Comment: If you are, see https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-7127?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Comment: when i type `SELECT VERSION()` I get `10.1.23-MariaDB`, so I think yes.

Comment: PCRE does not support collations.

Comment: @Barmar how can i solve this with mariaDB? Is it even possible?

Comment: I don't use MariaDB. Do you really need to use `[[.tilde.]]` instead of just putting `~` in the regexp?

Answer (score 1):

By the answers above I came to the answer to my similar error...
"POSIX named classes are supported only within a class"
Changed my DjangoDB from Postgresql to Mysql/MariaDB and had an error because of a special search pattern in my Django App:

`search_pattern = r'(-|[:space:]|/|[(]|[)])*%s' return Q(telefon__iregex=search) | Q(mobil__iregex=search)`

I replaced it by...

`search_pattern = r'(-| |/|[(]|[)])*%s' return Q(telefon__iregex=search) | Q(mobil__iregex=search)`

fixed it. Thus MariaDB really seems to not like the []-expressions...
Thanks for the hints!